# android save Bitmap failed?

Tags: android, bitmap, save, fileoutputstream

I made an online phase of the App

After which the user selects a picture.
Dialog will pop up the corresponding can be archived using the Dialog button.

But when I press the button when there is no error message appears

Show only:

```
11-20 11:26:53.968  25494-25494/com.book.test D/GestureDetector﹕ [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
```

I want to go to have saved the picture could not find.

Tell me how to fix my APP it?

Thank you

Open dialog:

```
   private void take(){
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(jd.this).create();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(jd.this);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null); // xml Layout file for imageView
    ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ttv);
    Button save = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
    img.setImageBitmap(Dl_Bp);
    save.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkSDCard();
            try {
                saveBitmap("sdcard",Dl_Bp,"uu.jpg");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });

    dialog.setView(view);
    dialog.show();
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

}
```

checkSDCard:

```
public static boolean checkSDCard() {
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Begin archiving behavior:

```
public static void saveBitmap(String pFolderPath, Bitmap pBitmap,
                              String pFileName) throws IOException {

    String _folderPath = pFolderPath;
    if (_folderPath.lastIndexOf("/") == -1) {
        _folderPath += "/";
    }
    File _file = new File(_folderPath + pFileName);
    OutputStream _outStream  = new FileOutputStream(_file);

    pBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, _outStream);

    _outStream.flush();
    _outStream.close();
}
```

Comment: first make sure you have "write permissions in Manifest." then put logs and check for SDCard,Filepath, and Write bitmap to File.

Answer (score 0):

according to your briefing about the problem,it looks like.click listener is not working.

1. Check that is your button click listener working by using some `Log.i();`
2. if yes than,do confirm that have you added `read write` permissions in **Manifest**.

hope this answer help you.

Comment: yes i have.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
I also have to check for DEBUG mode
Indeed the implementation of the code, but he is no action ..